# What does $ mean in MiniZinc?

Tags: minizinc

I see $ used in various places in the [MiniZinc Handbook](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.2/en/spec.html) (mostly in the [Reference Manual](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.2/en/part_4_reference.html) portion), but I haven't been able to find a definition. Would someone kindly explain it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniZinc supports three basic types, `{int, float, bool }`. The documentation uses `$T` as a place-holder for any type contained in this set, so that it is not necessary to provide three versions of each function's signature, one for each basic type.

I guess that this syntax style is inspired by the `shell`, where the notation `$T` is used to dereference the name `T` and it normally yields the value corresponding to such name/memory location.

One can also think as `$T` as a **template** `typename/class` in the `C++` language, that achieves the exact same purpose.

```cpp
// MiniZinc Docs
set of  $U:    array_union(array[$T]  of     set of  $U)

// C++-like style
template <class T, class U>
set<U> array_union(map< T, set<U> >);
```